# NodeJS: I am using ffmpeg inside the container and I think docker doesn't free memory

Tags: node.js, docker

I am using docker container to host a music bot using ffmpeg, with every song it processes it keeps on adding up to the memory and eventually runs of memory, is there any fix ? when using it on windows/linux without docker it works really fine only uses 150mb max and dosent even use more that 40% cpu but on docker it goes like 2.3 GB and dosent go down below that.

P.S i am using fluent-ffmpeg

Here is the `Docker File` -

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
USER root
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install curl gnupg
RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | bash -
RUN apt-get -y install nodejs
RUN apt install ffmpeg -y
COPY . .
RUN mkdir /app/storage/
RUN npm install
CMD ["node"  , "."]
```

Comment: It could be your nodejs script that is leaking memory.

Comment: No as i already said it dosent consume that much memory outside the container

Comment: Please post your code.